# Python Dataframe- count occurrences of list element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter

I have the following dataframe:

[image: Dataframe-df_train]

The basket_new column contains numbers from 0 to 5 in a list (the amount can vary for each number and transaction). I would like to count the occurrences of every number for each transaction and save that number in another DataFrame like this: [image: Counter Dataframe-df_cat]

I just created a lambda function for Cat_0 to test it, unfortunately it's not working as it is creating "None" entries (see picture 2).

This is the function:

```
df_cat["Cat_0"] = df_train["basket_new"].map(lambda x: df_cat["Cat_0"]+1 if "0" in x else None)
```

Can you please just tell me what I'm doing wrong / how to fix my issue?

Answer (score 2):

Use `explode` and `crosstab`.
Let say you have a df like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[[1,2],[0],[3,1,2,3],[4,2,2,2,1]]})
```

**df:**

```
    a   b
0   1   [1, 2]
1   2   [0]
2   3   [3, 1, 2, 3]
3   4   [4, 2, 2, 2, 1]
```

---

```
df1 = df['b'].explode()
df[['a', 'b']].join(pd.crosstab(df1.index, df1))
```

---

```
    a   b               0   1   2   3   4
0   1   [1, 2]          0   1   1   0   0
1   2   [0]             1   0   0   0   0
2   3   [3, 1, 2, 3]    0   1   1   2   0
3   4   [4, 2, 2, 2, 1] 0   1   3   0   1
```

---

If you want to rename columns:

```
df[['a', 'b']].join(pd.crosstab(df1.index, df1, colnames=['b']).add_prefix('cat_'))
```

---

```
    a   b               cat_0  cat_1  cat_2 cat_3 cat_4
0   1   [1, 2]          0      1      1     0     0
1   2   [0]             1      0      0     0     0
2   3   [3, 1, 2, 3]    0      1      1     2     0
3   4   [4, 2, 2, 2, 1] 0      1      3     0     1
```

Comment: This is probably a "better" answer than mine. More pandas-thonic. I'd also imagine much faster for large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`list.count()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/count) method:

```
df_cat["Cat_0"] = df['basket_new'].map(lambda x: x.count(0))
```

Using the first 5 rows of your data:

```
for i in range(0,5): df_cat["Cat_{0}".format(i)] = df['basket'].map(lambda x: x.count(i))

   Cat_0  Cat_1  Cat_2  Cat_3  Cat_4  Cat_5
0      0      0      0      1      0      0
1      1      0      0      2      0      1
2      0      1      0      1      1      1
3      0      0      1      0      0      0
4      0      0      0      0      4      0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather lengthy one but it works

```
df.explode('basket_new').groupby(['transaction_id','customerType','basket_new']).agg(count = ('basket_new','count'))\
.reset_index().pivot_table(index=['transaction_id','customerType'], columns='basket_new', values='count', fill_value=0)\
.reset_index()
```

[image]